# Nested Dictionaries returning KeyError when using .items() in a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I am using nested/embedded dictionaries as I have large quantity of information that I am working with. I was trying to get `.items()` to work for a smaller example of what I am doing. In the example I have two objects and each object has multiple lines such as `'Mg II'` or `'C I'` and each line has corresponding data such as its `'center'` or `'continuum_range'`. I need to be able to call the `' center'` or `'continuum_range'` for a function I am performing but am unable to call it in a for loop without a `KeyError`. I know similar questions have been asked, but I am not experienced enough to understand them in way that applies to my problem. Any advice is appreciated.

This is the code I tried. The section with `for line, params in line_params.items():` was given to me as a better way to do what I was doing but I don't think I am using it correctly.

```
objs = ['star1', 'star2']

#for line, params in line_params.items():
    
star1= {'Mg_II': {'center':[5], 'continuum_range':[10,20]},
             'C_1': {'center':[6], 'continuum_range':[12,24]}
             }
  
star2= {'Mg_II': {'center':[8], 'continuum_range':[16,32]},
             'C_1': {'center':[7], 'continuum_range':[14,21]}
             }  

line_params= {'star1': star1, 'star2': star2}

'''
for obj in objs:
    print(line_params[obj]['Mg_II']['center'])
    break
#works   
'''

for obj in objs:
    for line, params in line_params.items():
        print(params['center'])
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please think carefully about the logic of the code. In the working version, when you do `line_params[obj]['Mg_II']['center']`, what does `line_params` look like at that point? What indexing do you do, in order to get the desired result? Therefore, in the non-working code - what is `params`? What does it look like, and *how does that compare to* the original, working `line_params` values? Therefore, what indexing makes sense?

Answer (score -1):

Here are some pointers.

First, I noticed that you did this:

```
objs = ['star1', 'star2']
```

Now, the problem with this is though you have defined star1 and star2 as dictionaries, you enclosed them in single quotes. When you do that, you are actually creating a STRING instead of referencing the variables you have created.

So, the first correction is to do this instead:

```
objs = [star1, star2]
```

Next, this line is actually correct:

```
for line, params in line_params.items():
```

You just need to learn how to use it.

When you say

```
for line, params
```

You are unpacking 2 variables: line and params.

To understand what variables you are unpacking, you can simply do this:

```
print(line_params.items())
```

And you will get the following result:

```
dict_items([('star1', {'Mg_II': {'center': [5], 'continuum_range': [10, 20]}, 'C_1': {'center': [6], 'continuum_range': [12, 24]}}), ('star2', {'Mg_II': {'center': [8], 'continuum_range': [16, 32]}, 'C_1': {'center': [7], 'continuum_range': [14, 21]}})])
```

Now if you notice, you are getting a list of tuples.
A tuple follows the following format:

```
(key, key)
```

In this case, a single tuple looks like:

```
('star1', {my dict here})
```

So that means that line pertains to the variable name of the dictionary whereas params refers to the actual dictionary.

So, the correct version of this:

```
print(params['center'])
```

Is this:

```
print(params['Mg_II']['center'])
```

Putting everything together, the working code is:

```
star1= {'Mg_II': {'center':[5], 'continuum_range':[10,20]},
             'C_1': {'center':[6], 'continuum_range':[12,24]}
             }
  
star2= {'Mg_II': {'center':[8], 'continuum_range':[16,32]},
             'C_1': {'center':[7], 'continuum_range':[14,21]}
             }  

objs = [star1, star2] # do not enclose in ' or else it will read as a string
line_params= {'star1': star1, 'star2': star2}

for obj in objs:
    for line, params in line_params.items():
        print(params['Mg_II']['center'])
```

Additionally, a cleaner version of the code is as follows:

```
star1= {'Mg_II': {'center':[5], 'continuum_range':[10,20]},
             'C_1': {'center':[6], 'continuum_range':[12,24]}
             }
  
star2= {'Mg_II': {'center':[8], 'continuum_range':[16,32]},
             'C_1': {'center':[7], 'continuum_range':[14,21]}
             }  

objs = [star1, star2] # do not enclose in ' or else it will read as a string

for obj in objs:
    for item in objs:
        print(item['Mg_II']['center'])
```

This is cleaner because we removed the following line:

```
line_params= {'star1': star1, 'star2': star2}
```

Which is actually unnecessary if all you need to do is access the dictionary elements. You can skip to simply accessing the dictionaries directly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this, it really helped. My only question is how I would generalize this to multiple lines (Mg_II, C_I....) which is my main issue.

Comment: If you do `print(item)` you will get all the contents of star1 and star2. Now notice you have 2 root keys: Mg_II and C_1. If you want to access the contents of those elements, all you have to do is `print(item["Mg_II"]` or `print(item["C_1"])`.